# Why Laravel does not recognize a relation? Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::model()

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

This is one of those "I changed nothing and it stopped working" cases. A month ago my deployed version of a project on the server was working fine, today I have pushed some changes that had nothing to do with model relationships and it suddenly started throwing me this error.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::websites()
```

Part of the script that's throwing this error

```
if(!empty($websites))
      {
        $filePdf->websites()->attach($websites);
      }
```

$filePdf is of type App\File, I have checked that with get_class()

Here are the defined relationships
App\File.php

```
public function websites()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\website', 'file_websites', 'file_id', 'website_id');
}
```

App\website.php

```
public function files()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\File', 'file_websites', 'website_id', 'file_id');
}
```

Table structure of the file_websites

```
Schema::create('file_websites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('file_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('website_id');

        $table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('files');
        $table->foreign('website_id')->references('id')->on('websites');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

On my local machine, it's working fine, no errors but once I deploy it, this starts happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
Here's how $filePdf is declared

```
$filePdf= new File();
$filePdf->filename = $name;
$filePdf->language_id = $request->input('fileLanguage');
$filePdf->save();
```

Comment: what is $filePdf , show us more

Comment: The error message in the title is different from that of your post.

Comment: Are you actually using your `File.php` model? I.e. using `File::...` to start your query. Or are you using `DB::table('files')`?

Comment: @TimLewis yes, I am 
$filePdf= new File();
$filePdf->filename = $name;
$filePdf->language_id = $request->input('fileLanguage');
$filePdf->save();

Comment: @Jeto I generalized my issue for people with similar problems. websites() is my issue, but I would generally search for model() on google

Answer (score -1):

try to change 'App\website' to 'App\Website'

```
public function websites()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Website', 'file_websites', 'file_id', 'website_id');
}
```

Comment: Nope, my websites file is actually with lower w - website.php

Comment: you website class also lower?

Comment: yes,     
class website extends Model
{
    //
    public function files()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\File', 'file_websites', 'website_id', 'file_id');
    }

    public function tags(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'tags_websites', 'website_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}